# Issue with JFXSlider and ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

I'm having an issue with a JFXSlider and a ScrollPane. Since I don't like the default style of the scrollbar, I'm using a JFXSlider to move the ScrollPane up and down.

```
slider.valueProperty().addListener((ChangeListener) ->
        scrollPane.setVvalue(Math.abs(slider.getValue() - 100) / 100));
```

This piece of code works just fine, but when I add content to the ScrollPane, it stays in its place. I would like to move it to the bottom.
I've tried changing the position of the ScrollPane after inserting the contents,
but it does nothing.

```
anchorPane.localToScene();
scrollPane.setVvalue();
```

I also tried to bind the ScrollPane vValue to the height of the vBox that it has inside and it worked, but the JFXSlider stopped working

```
scrollPane.vvalueProperty().bind(vBox.heightProperty());
```

I would like to have both working at the same time, but I don't know if it's possible. I've heard about bindBidirectional, but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you ensure the range of your slider is the same as the vertical range of your scroll pane, which you can do with

```
slider.minProperty().bind(scrollPane.vminProperty());
slider.maxProperty().bind(scrollPane.vmaxProperty());
```

then you can just bidirectionally bind the slider's value to the scrollpane's vertical value:

```
slider.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(scrollPane.vvalueProperty());
```

(I don't use JFoenix, and I can't find any meaningful documentation for it, so I'm just assuming here that a `JFXSlider` has the same properties as a standard `Slider`.)